# Batch file loop - run all files that meet findstr criteria

Tags: batch-file

Can someone advise where I have gotten wrong? I'm looking to run all files in a folder where the filename contains the word Expenses

```
cd /D Z:\System Administrator\System Backups\Scripts\

FINDSTR /S /M "expenses" *.*

FOR /F %%i in ('findstr /I /S /M "expenses" *.py') DO command %%i
```

findstr will get me the list of files I need, I just can't get them to run and get the error that command is not recognised as an internal or external command.

The list of files will be
Expenses 2017-18.py
Expenses 2018-19.py
etc

Thanks in advance

UPDATE
I have found that this works, although I welcome any improvements

```
for /R %%f in (*expenses*.py) do start python "%%f"
```

Comment: `findstr /m` will return all files, where the word `expenses` is *in the content of the file` but doesn't check the filename iteself. You simply need `for ... in (*expenses*.py) do...` (that's called a "file mask"). Given your example file names, `expenses*.py` would suffice. Oh - and your filenames contain spaces, so `do command "%%i"`

Comment: I think I understand ... so I tried 
FOR "%%i" in (expenses*.py) DO command "%%i" but this still doesn't work. The bat file doesn't pause when it should so I cant see any error message

Comment: Please see update, I have found a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what is being sought is the instruction to actually *execute* the python files `%%i`. I'm no python expert - I don't know whether you need to simply use `whatever.py` from the prompt or `somexecutablename whatever.py`.

I believe that you'd probably need `call "%%i"` to run the files serially or, to run in parallel, use `start "" "%%i"`. In either case, if you need `somexecutablename` then insert that before `"%%i"`.

The empty string in the `start` version is the windowtitle. It's really needs to be there, even if empty - but you could replace it with `"%%i"` to show the executing filename as the window title.

Comment: You are correct in that i want to execute all py files that contain the word Expenses. For other files I can simply put the file path and it will run.  However I want to future proof this process, hence using the FINDSTR which lists the files I need. I just can't get it to *do* anything with them.  So I tried    FOR "%%i" in (expenses*.py) DO command  CALL "%%i" and got the error that i was unexpected at this time.  I didn't think this would be such a unique problem as I am struggling to find other help topics on this... I might just go back to hard coding the filenames.

Comment: Please see update, I have found a solution that works.

Comment: `%%i` is batch file syntax. For use directly on command line, use `%i` only (as explained in `for /?`). Oh - and it's `for %%i in ...`, not `for "%%i" in ...`